# Resize/change Header Image in responsive HTML-Email

Tags: html, css, image, html-email

I want to re-size the header image to fit the container (proportionally) when it's re-sized with media queries due to smaller screen size.

Current CSS Code:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 660px) {
        table.container { width: 480px !important; }

        td.headline { padding: 5px 0px 0px 30px !important}
        td.headline h1 { font-size: 28px !important}

    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 510px) {
        table.container { width: 320px !important; }



        td.headline { padding: 5px 0px 0px 30px !important; }
        td.headline h1 { font-size: 22px !important; text-align: center; }

    }
```

I tried:

Resizing with an inline style; does not re-size when the second threshold is crossed stated in the css query:

```
<table class="container" width="1000" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                        <td valign="top" class="header" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px"; border-left: 1px solid #dbc064; border-right: 1px solid #dbc064; border-top: 1px solid #dbc064;>
                        <a href="http://www.reha-com-tech.de/">
                        <img id="banner" src="images/header_large.jpg" alt="Reha-Com-Tech" style="max-width:100%; height: auto;" width="100%" height="auto"></a>
                        </td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>                                
                        <td valign="top" class="headline" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 15px 20px 5px 30px; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid #ffffff; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px;">
                        <h1 style="margin:0px 0px 15px 0px; font-weight:normal; font-size:32px; color:#000000;">Newsletter zur Frühlings-Aktion 2016</h>
                        </td>
                </tr>
```

Using image replace with smaller images when rendered on smaller screen sizes, does somehow not work, it just disables the image instead of replacing it:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 660px) {
        table.container { width: 480px !important; }
        td.header img {display: none;}
        td. header { width: 480px; height: 108px; url(images/header_medium.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px}

        td.headline { padding: 5px 0px 0px 30px !important}
        td.headline h1 { font-size: 28px !important}
```

Also tried autoresize (example below) with CSS, always a gap between the header and the table end on the right:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .banner{
        height:auto !important;
        max-width:600px !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

To get a better picture, here are two screenshots of the newsletter:

Pic1
[Normal Full-size render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQUtq.png)
Pic2
[480px render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prtqI.png)

And now, for all the brave ones who are willing to wander through a newb-code, the whole HTML ;)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Reha-Com-Tech Newsletter</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    @media only screen and (max-width: 660px) {
        table.container { width: 480px !important; }

        td.headline { padding: 5px 0px 0px 30px !important}
        td.headline h1 { font-size: 28px !important}

    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 510px) {
        table.container { width: 320px !important; }



        td.headline { padding: 5px 0px 0px 30px !important; }
        td.headline h1 { font-size: 22px !important; text-align: center; }

    }


    </style>
</head> 
<body bgcolor="#f5be3d">

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f5be3d">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="container" width="1000" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                        <td valign="top" class="header" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px"; border-left: 1px solid #dbc064; border-right: 1px solid #dbc064; border-top: 1px solid #dbc064;>
                        <a href="http://www.reha-com-tech.de/">
                        <img id="banner" src="images/header_large.jpg" alt="Reha-Com-Tech" style="max-width:100%; height: auto;" width="100%" height="auto"></a>
                        </td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>                                
                        <td valign="top" class="headline" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 15px 20px 5px 30px; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid #ffffff; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px;">
                        <h1 style="margin:0px 0px 15px 0px; font-weight:normal; font-size:32px; color:#000000;">Newsletter zur Frühlings-Aktion 2016</h>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                                
                        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#f5f2e5" class="content" style="padding: 30px 30px 10px 30px; border-right: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; line-height:22px; color: #654308;">
                        Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren, sehr geehrte Geschäftspartner,<br>
                        <br>
                        Dies ist ein Test-Newsletter! Sehen Sie sich um! Angebote nur befristet gültig!<br>
                        <br>
                        Mit freundlichen Grüßen <br>
                        <br>
                        i.A. Marcel Wambsganss <br> <br> 
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                                
                        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#f5f2e5" class="promos" style="padding: 10px 30px 25px 30px; border-right:1px solid #dbc064; border-left:1px solid #dbc064; background-color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                        <table class="promo_1" width="270" align="left">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                <img class="promo" alt="Promo image 1" src="images/promo_1_large.jpg">
                                <h3 style="font-size:16px;">Bellman Visit Telefonsender BE1430</h3>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua elit sed do eiusmod.
                                <br><br>
                                <a href="http://p269195.webspaceconfig.de/shop/product_info.php?info=p60_bellman-visit-telefonsender-be1430.html&XTCsid=dfske903dfgt23nqnal2dpulg4" style="background-color: #71a412; border-radius: 5px; color: #fff; padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #3a5606;">Mehr</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table class="promo_2" width="270" align="right">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                <img class="promo" alt="Promo image 1" src="images/promo_2_large.jpg">
                                <h3 style="font-size:16px;">Relation 2 (Phonic Ear)</h3>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua elit sed do eiusmod.
                                <br><br>
                                <a href="http://p269195.webspaceconfig.de/shop/product_info.php?info=p233_relation-2--phonic-ear-.html" style="background-color: #71a412; border-radius: 5px; color: #fff; padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #3a5606;">Mehr</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        </td> 

                </tr> 
                <tr>                            
                        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#b7b7b7" class="callout" style="background-color: #b7b7b7; padding: 30px; border-right: 1px solid #b7b7b7; border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b7b7; border-left: 1px solid #b7b7b7;">
                            <table class="callout_1" width="140" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" width="135" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height: 16px; color: #ffffff;">
                                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/reha.com.tech/"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="75" height="75"></a><br><br>
                                        Besuchen sie uns auch in den sozialen Netzwerken:
                                        <br><br><br><br>
                                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/reha.com.tech/" style="color:#ffffff">Facebook</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table class="callout_2" width="140" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" width="135" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height: 16px; color: #ffffff;">
                                        <a href="mailto:service@reha-com-tech.de"><img src="images/email.png" width="75" height="75"></a><br><br>
                                        Haben sie Fragen oder ein sonstiges Anliegen? Schreiben Sie uns!
                                        <br><br><br>
                                    <a href="mailto:service@reha-com-tech.de" style="color:#ffffff">Email</a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            <table class="callout_3" width="140" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" width="140" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 16px; color: #ffffff;">
                                        <img src="images/telefon.png" width="75" height="75"><br><br>
                                        Fon:    06519945680<br>
                                        Fax:    06519945681<br>
                                        Skype:<br>reha-com-tech
                                        <br><br><br>
                                    <a href="#" style="color:#ffffff">Telefon</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            <table class="callout_4" width="140" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" width="135" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 16px; color: #ffffff;">
                                        <a href="http://reha-com-tech.de"><img src="images/web.png" width="75" height="75"></a><br><br>
                                        Besuchen sie uns im Web!
                                        <br><br><br><br><br>
                                        <a href="http://www.reha-com-tech.de/" style="color:#ffffff">Website</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            <table class="callout_5" width="140" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" width="135" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 16px; color: #ffffff;">
                                        <a href="http://p269195.webspaceconfig.de/shop/shop_content.php?coID=1201"><img src="images/shopping.png" width="75" height="75"></a><br><br>
                                        Informationen rund um den Bestellvorgang.
                                        <br><br><br><br>
                                        <a href="http://p269195.webspaceconfig.de/shop/shop_content.php?coID=1201" style="color:#ffffff">Shopinformationen</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            <table class="callout_6" width="140" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" width="135" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 16px; color: #ffffff;">
                                        <a href="http://p269195.webspaceconfig.de/shop/shop_content.php?coID=200"><img src="images/logo_bw.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a><br><br>
                                        Erfahren sie mehr über uns.
                                        <br><br><br><br><br>
                                        <a href="http://p269195.webspaceconfig.de/shop/shop_content.php?coID=200" style="color:#ffffff">Reha-Com-Tech</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>                    
                        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#b7b7b7" class="impressum" style="background-color: #b7b7b7; padding: 30px; border-right: 1px solid #b7b7b7; border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b7b7; border-left: 1px solid #b7b7b7;">
                        <table class="callout_1" width="500" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" width="135" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height: 16px; color: #ffffff;">
                                        Impressum:<br><br>
                                        Reha-Technik &
                                        Kommunikationstechnik
                                        für Hörgeschädigte<br><br>

                                        Schönbornstr. 1
                                        D-54295 Trier<br><br>

                                        Fon: + 49 (0) 651-99 45 680<br>
                                        Fax: + 49 (0) 651-99 45 681<br><br>

                                        E-mail: info@reha-com-tech.de <br><br>

                                        Alleinvertretungsberechtigt:
                                        Ralf Oedekoven e.K.<br><br>

                                        Handelsregister:<br>
                                        HRA 4748 Registergericht Wittlich
                                        USt.-IDNr.: DE 157 829 984<br><br>

                                        WEEE-Reg.-Nr.: DE14064765<br><br>
                                        <a href="http://p269195.webspaceconfig.de/shop/shop_content.php?coID=4&XTCsid=nstnqgv7uu9qug727dqgln3ia0">Impressum</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table><td>
                        </td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                        <td valign="top" class="footer" style="padding: 10px 0px 30px 0px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #b2a16e;">
                        &copy; Reha-Com-Tech. Bitte antorten sie nicht auf diese Mail.
                        <br><br>
                        Möchten sie den Newsletter nicht mehr erhalten, genügt eine kurze Nachricht an:<a href="mailto:info@reha-com-tech" style="color:#000000;">info@reha-com-tech</a>.
                        <br><br>
                        Diese E-Mail enthält vertrauliche und/oder rechtlich geschützte Informationen. Sollten Sie nicht der Empfänger sein, für den diese Mail bestimmt ist, so informieren Sie bitte sofort den Absender und löschen Sie diese E-Mail. Das unerlaubte Weiterleiten und das unbefugte Kopieren dieser E-Mail sowie der Anhänge sind nicht gestattet.

                        </td>
                </tr> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

Comment: Media queries aren't well supported in emails.

Comment: Are you sending the email via php? Or you're using a third part service? Have you tested this code in a html or php document? Is it working? Can you post the `<head>` content? You'll probably need to set the MIME type and also the `width=device-width` meta tag.

Comment: @andi Is there a better solution to scale the HTML-Newsletter to different screen sizes mainly for mobile devices? I plan to send it from my home PC using the App "Supermailer", http://www.supermailer.de/ , it can do normal html code

Comment: @VirtuaCreative i edited the Post, at the end is my whole code :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I tried to handle the html e-mail with @media rules, but I did something that worked well enough for me. I'll add it as an answer and you can check if this help you out. ;)

Comment: @VirtuaCreative Thank you very much for your time! :)

Comment: No problem! ;) There it goes... Hope it works for you. For me it does! :)

Comment: oops... I haven't seen this part of your comment: `I plan to send it from my home PC using the App "Supermailer", supermailer.de , it can do normal html code` . Perhaps just bringing your styles to in-line styles and adding this `<meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimal-ui">` to the `<head>` will do the job. Or you can try MailChimp instead, which is quite simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `@media` rules, you can try to adapt your code to giving a `width: 100%` when you need resizable or responsive blocks.

This works for me:

***First: HTML markup***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimal-ui">
        </head>
        <body style="
            max-width: 100%;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
            /* add as many styles as you need here to the email body */
            ">
```

Try using inline styles to each part. It helped me out, might work for you too. For example:

```
<h1 align="justify" style="font-size:18px; color: rgb(0,0,0); text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgb(108,108,108);">
....
<table rules="all" style="border-color: #999; width:95%; margin-right: 5px" cellpadding="5">
```

***Second: PHP form handler***

Suppose you'll be sending the e-mail via php, you'll need to specify this onto your php `headers`:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $your_name <$your_email>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $your_name <$your_email>\r\n";

...
```

Which works with this mail function:

```
mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers, -fyouremail@yourdomain.com');
```

Now.... If you're having too mush trouble to set those things up, you can try [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com), which is a third-part newsletter/email service very well established.

Hope to have helped! If I did, please consider marking this answer as usefull and/or correct. Thanks!

Comment: As you can see [here](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/), the recommended method is using inline styles only when sending html emails.